# Using three IFs vs using IF-ELIF-ELSE: former is faster

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, python-3.5

I wrote a code to find the [ugly numbers](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/?p=753). While trying to make it faster, I found that using 3 IFs instead of an IF-ELIF-ELSE made my code faster. I tried running the code for multiple iterations of n and found that this is true most of the time.

I feel that IF-ELIF-ELSE should be faster since if one of the conditions is met, it would not go into the others. But I am unable to find any logic in what actually happened.

Here is the code:

```
ugly = [0]*n
ugly[0] = 1
i2, i3, i5 = 0, 0, 0

count = 1

while count<n:
    n2 = ugly[i2]*2
    n3 = ugly[i3]*3
    n5 = ugly[i5]*5

    next = min(n2, n3, n5)

    if next==n2:
        i2 += 1
    elif next==n3:
        i3 += 1
    else:
        i5 += 1

    if next != ugly[count-1]:
        ugly[count] = next
        count += 1
```

Comment: Perhaps you should post this question at Code Review https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've not worked through the sequence produced by your code, but can `n2`, `n3` or `n5` ever be equal to each other? If so, you might be getting a different result from your three `if`s (since more than one will be matched).

Comment: @Blckknght Yes, some of `n2`, `n3` and `n5` are frequently equal. Well spotted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two versions of your code don't compute the results the same way, so it shouldn't be too big of a surprise that they take different amounts of time.

When you use `if`/`elif`/`else`, you'll often compute the same `next` value several times. For instance, six can be computed as `2*3` or `3*2`. Since only one of the `i2`, `i3`, `i5` values will be incremented when `6` is the minimum of `n2`, `n3`, `n5`, you'll end up picking `i2` to increment on the first pass, and then `i3` on a second pass, since `n3` is still six. The `if next != ugly[count-1]:` check will prevent the duplicate values from ending up in the output, but you still need to run the loop body an extra time.

When you use multiple `if`s, all the `i` values that generate the minimum `n` value will be incremented at the same time. This means you'll only compute each ugly number once, even if it can be generated several different ways. Avoiding the extra work means the code runs faster. You could also get rid of the `if next != ugly[count-1]:` guard code, since you'll never generate the same value repeatedly.

Answer (score 1):

not sure to be able to explain, but it seems to me that you want the fastest approach and your code

- is calling `min` performs a function call + a loop + comparisons
- then it's comparing the minimum with 2 of the 3 values

that is a *lot* of tests. Specially calling `min` for 3 values is overkill.

I've rewritten your loop without `min` (if the values are equal, `min` returns the leftmost parameter, as an implementation detail for Python 2, and now guaranteed for python 3) only using inequality tests (chaining the operators)

```
while count<n:
    n2 = ugly[i2]*2
    n3 = ugly[i3]*3
    n5 = ugly[i5]*5

    if n5 >= n2 <= n3:
        next = n2
        i2+=1
    elif n5 >= n3 <= n2:
        next = n3
        i3 += 1
    else:
        next = n5
        i5 += 1

    # below: not changed
    if next != ugly[count-1]:
        ugly[count] = next
        count += 1
```

since there are only 3 numbers to compare, testing like this is faster.

For `n=2000000` on my machine:

- your approach: 7.78 seconds
- my approach: 6.32 seconds

Both codes produce the same result of course.

Note that I wouldn't call my variable `next` as it is a built-in function